# Associate public ip address if subnet is b. Will it work?

Tags: terraform

I have more then two subnets in my locals and want to create two instance for each subnets but when tf create ec2 for subnet b, it should assign public address true and false for other subnets. Will below code works? Concern is that, at a time only one subnet I can access in ec2 resource from for_each loop, so how would be identify, is this subnet b?

```
locals {
  eks-vpc-insts = {
    a = "subnet-0afa7ab81984"
    b = "subnet-0205cf9123bc"
    c= "subnet-0dd1fea869ee"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "du-indexer" {

  ami        = "ami-8a446ffe"
  key_name   = "xyz"
  monitoring = true

  instance_type = "r5a.large"

  vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-020d9ca69"]

  for_each = {
    for k,v in local.eks-vpc-insts : k => v
    if v != local.eks-vpc-insts.c
  }

  subnet_id                   = each.value
  
  associate_public_ip_address =  each.value == local.eks-vpc-insts.b  ? true : false
  tags = {
    Name   = "indexer-${each.key}"
    Db     = "druid"
    DUNode = "indexer"
  }

  root_block_device {
    volume_size = 40
    volume_type = "gp2"
  }
}
```

Comment: So you want two instances but only one should be assigned a public IP? Why not run the code and see what happens?

Comment: What's wrong with the current code?

Comment: @Marcin, My Aim was to create two instance even if there are three value in locals and on top of that, apply only public ip address if subnets if B. And as per my last edit, it works. Thanks you for look my question!